# Why do I get Error: Exceeded maximum number of tasks allowed per rule (10) when deploying a workflow via ANT?

Tags: workflow, deployment, limits, ant

I have a workflow rule that are failing to be deployed to a sandbox from a sandbox via ANT.

The workflow rule has seven field update tasks associated to it.

When I deploy I get this error message.
Error: Exceeded maximum number of tasks allowed per rule (10)

I'm sure I've got less than ten field update tasks on the workflow rule so why am I getting this message and what can I do to resolve it?

My next step is to try to deploy the workflow using a change set to see if I get the same error there.

Answer (score 1):

I found that because the workflow already existed in the target organisation the deployment process was unable to overwrite the existing tasks and so was adding them instead.

To resolve the problem I deleted the workflow rule in the target system and re-ran the deployment.

Comment: It can be tricky to see what is in a target environment, and what state the object is in. Full disclosure that I work for these guys, but we've started https://gearset.com to make deployments easier and provide you with visibility into what state your orgs are in. If you have any feedback on it let me know.